# How can i make 3 div blocks auto height and at the same the same height

Tags: html, css, flexbox

I use auto height on my website so that the height will change with how much content is in the div. But I need 3 divs in the same row to have the same height even when being resized (responsive).

Currently, div 1 or 2 get a different height with resizing the browser.

Is there a way to code this so that all three will stay to have the same height no matter how much you resize for responsiveness?

CSS:

```
#integel {
    background-color:rgba(255,255,255,1);
height:auto;
width:30%;
    min-height: 30em;
display:inline-block;
    line-height:2.3vw;
      overflow:hidden;
    float:left;
    margin-top:0%;
    margin-bottom:5%;
    margin-left:2.5%;
    margin-right:0%;
    color:black;
    border:solid rgba(63, 146, 195, 1) 0.3vmax;
    }




#integel1 {
    background-color:rgba(255,255,255,1);
height:auto;
width:30%;
    min-height: 30vmax;
display:table-row;
    line-height:2.3vw;
      overflow:hidden;
    float:left;
    margin-top:0%;
    margin-bottom:5%;
    margin-left:2.5%;
    margin-right:0%;
    color:black;    
    border:solid rgba(63, 146, 195, 1) 0.3vmax;
}

#integel3 {
    background-color:rgba(255,255,255,1);
height:auto;
        min-height: 30vmax;
width:30%;
display:inline-block;
    line-height:2.3vw;
      overflow:hidden;
    float:left;
    margin-top:0%;
    margin-bottom:5%;
    margin-left:2.5%;
    margin-right:0%;
    color:black;
        border:solid rgba(63, 146, 195, 1) 0.3vmax;
}
```

As you can see at [www.gester.nl](http://www.gester.nl) (at the services part)

Comment: Firs to all, provide a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) so we can help without accessing external links. Use `display: flex;` on the element containing your three `div`s, and give the container the `align-items: stretch;` rule to stretch the children to the same height. [Click here for more info on flexbox rules](https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/a-guide-to-flexbox/).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

#### *Hi*

I take elements of site linked by you. If they should be like now (3 in first line, fourth alone with full size) you have snippet here below. If you want to have 4 in one line just change `flex` of `#services div` to 25% and delete `flex`  for `#services div:last-child`.

```css
#services {
  display: flex;
  flex-flow: row wrap;
  justify-content: space-between;
  align-content: center;
}

#services div {
  border: 1px solid tomato;
  flex: 0 0 30%;
}

#services div:last-child {
  margin-top: 10px;
  border: 1px solid royalblue;
  flex: 0 0 100%;
}
```

```html
<div id="services">
   <div id="integel">
   
    <p class="prijsinfo">Bent u opzoek naar een unieke website? Ik creëer speciaal voor u een unieke stijl. Een <b>HTML website</b> laten bouwen, uiteraard responsive ook op mobiel en tablet. U kunt zelf niks veranderen aan de inhoud, daarvoor ben ik hier voor u(*Gratis). <br>
<br>

  Een <b>HTML website</b> is geschikt als er bijna nooit iets aangepast hoeft te worden. Als uw website veel gewijzigd moet worden en als u zelf teksten en foto's wilt wijzigen, dan is een <b>CMS website</b> perfect voor u!<br>
<br>
Bekijk voorbeeldwebsites in mijn <a id="link" class="link1" href="javascript:;">portfolio</a> of ga naar <a class="link2" id="link" href="javascript:;">contact</a>.

</p>
 <p class="prijs">
 *Prijs HTML website vanaf 69,99 euro,- 
</p></div>
 
   <div id="integel3">
    <p class="prijsinfo"> Of wilt u liever een voorbeeld website van WordPress. Hierbij ontwerpen wij niet de vormgeving, u kiest eenvoudig uit meer dan duizend vormgeving thema's. Dit is ook responsive voor mobiel en tablet. Op deze manier hoeven wij de vormgeving niet te creëren en duurt het maximaal 2 dagen*.</p>
 <a href="https://nl.wordpress.org/themes/browse/popular" target="_blank"><img id="themas" src="images/wordpress.jpg"></a>

<br>
<br>
<br>

<p class="prijs">*Prijs voorbeeld(WordPress)website vanaf 44,99 euro,-</p> 
  
 </div>
  <div id="integel1">
   <p class="prijsinfo">Een <b>CMS website</b> staat voor Content Management System: u kunt zelf makkelijk vanaf thuis de inhoud van uw website veranderen. Dit word ook gemaakt met een unieke vormgeving en helemaal responsive voor mobiel en tablet. Het is door het systeem makkelijk om pagina's aan te maken, maar ook tekst, foto's en filmpjes. Het is daarom handig om voor dit pakket te kiezen als u zelf veel inhoud wilt aanpassen.<br>
<br>
 Wees niet gevreesd over de complexiteit, het werkt ongeveer alsof u in een tekstverwerker werkt. Het is heel eenvoudig en als u vragen heeft kunt u altijd <a id="link" class="link2" href="javascript:;">contact</a> met ons opnemen.
<br>


<br> 
 </p>


 <p class="prijs">*Prijs CMS website vanaf 179,99 euro,-</p>
  
  </div>

  <div id="integel2">
   <p class="onderinfo">
 Ik heb 2 jaar ervaring en ik heb veel geleerd. Daarom ben ik er nu klaar voor om voor u wat mooi's te maken. Ik vind dat alle websites teveel op elkaar lijken, doordat mensen een standaard style voor hun website gebruiken. Hierdoor wil ik op deze manier proberen om daar doorheen te breken met mijn creativiteit. Uw website hoort uniek te zijn, daarbij horen uw ideeën en wensen. Ik ben zeer gepassioneerd over het maken van websites en ik leer steeds meer en meer. Ik ben enthousiast, klantgericht en betrouwbaar met veel motivatie. De volgende stap voor mij om te leren is hoe ik een webshop website kan maken.<br>
<br>
Wij werken met Wordpress: Wordpress <b>Content Management System</b>.
Wordpress is het beste CMS op dit moment. Het heeft veel uitbreidingsmogelijkheden(plugins) en het is veilig.<br>

<br>
U kunt een website website uitbreiden door:<br>
<br>

Meertalig te maken.<br>

Responsive te maken voor mobiele telefoons en tablets en nog veel meer.<br>
<br>
 Voor meer vragen en wensen kunt u <a id="link" class="link2" href="javascript:;">contact</a> met ons opnemen.
<br>
<br>
Om de websites te bekijken die ik gemaakt heb ga naar <a id="link" class="link1" href="javascript:;">portfolio</a>.
<br>
<br>

*Prijs is exclusief btw.<br>
*HTML website - Alle tekst en foto's bewerken zijn 2x per jaar gratis, daarna geldt bij ons het uurtarief.
<br>
*WordPress thema website uitwerken duurt 2 dagen bij weinig pagina's en inhoud. 

</p>
 
<p class="prijs">Uurtarief: 19,99 euro,-</p>
 
   
  </div>
 </div>
```

More about CSS3 Flexbox you can find e.g. [on W3Schools page](https://www.w3schools.com/css/css3_flexbox.asp).

Hope that was helpful.

#### *Cheers*

Comment: This is magical, it is so nice and responsive. THANKYOU for your time

Answer (score 0):

Use FLexbox!

Something like this:

```
.wrapper {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction:row;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  justify-content: space-between;
}

.col {
  width: 30%;
  padding: 1%;
}
```

[A js Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/jur435kv/5/)